# Updating a C# array inside C++ without Marshal.Copy or Unsafe

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

I am wanting to update an array that was created inside C#, and then pass a pointer to that array over to C++ and let C++ populate the indexes, to be used back in C#. Right now I am Using a Marshal.Copy() to accomplish this task, but I would like to avoid the potentially unnecessary copy, and call back to c++ to release the array. Is this even possible?

These array are floats and ints, for geometric mesh data.

My current usage (working and not what I want to use)
C#

```
    IntPtr intptr=new IntPtr();
    int count = 0;
    PopulateArray(ref intptr, ref count);
    float[] resultVertices = new float[count];
    Marshal.Copy(intptr, resultVertices, 0, count);
```

C++

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool PopulateArray(float** resultVerts, int* resultVertLength){

    *resultVerts = new float[5]{0.123f, 3.141529f, 127.001f, 42.42f, 0};
    int myX = 5;
    *resultVertLength = myX;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use unsafe code? You already call C++

Comment: *Is this even possible?* --  Why would you think it's not possible?  Can't C# call Windows API functions using `pinvoke` that do exactly as you describe, i.e. C# passes a pointer to a buffer, and the API fills the buffer?

Comment: Yes, that's possible.  Doesn't require unsafe code either.  What kind of help you need to get there is *completely* unguessable.

Comment: Manuel Amstutz
This code will be getting ported to Unity3D at some point, and Unity can have issues building Unsafe C# to some platforms.

PaulMcKenzie
I know it is functionally possible but I would prefer doing it without having to do excessive amounts of data copying several times a second.

Comment: If you could post some sample code showing how you are currently accomplishing this via `Marshal.Copy` that would provide way to see if this can be done.

Comment: @BrandonFarrell In your code, who is responsible for calling `delete[ ]`?

Comment: @ nicholas It is pretty boiler plate from MSDN examples all I am doing is getting a pointer, and passing that to c++ and having c++ update what it is pointing to. then do a marshal.copy on that.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie not directly applicable to my question but C# calls a release. One of the things I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @BrandonFarrell No. C# is not C++.  When you call `new[ ]` in C++, you have to call `delete[ ]` at some point.  It is not the same thing as a C# `new`.  Also, I don't understand about data copying -- you create the buffer in C#, pass a pointer to this buffer to C++, have C++ fill it in.  Done.  Where is the excessive copying?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes, C# calls the extern function in c++ that releases that data. With Marshal.Copy, takes the naitive floats, and migrates it into manged C# float[]

Comment: @BrandonFarrell, can you change the call signature on the C++ side?

Comment: @nicholas if i am understanding your question correctly, yes. I am writing both the C++ and C# implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only safe way to have C++ code update a managed C# array is to pin the array. Otherwise, it's possible for the garbage collector to try to move the array while the native code is running. You can do this with a GCHandle object.

```
int count = 5; 
float[] resultVertices = new float[count];

GCHandle handle = GCHandle.Alloc(resultVertices, GCHandleType.Pinned);
IntPtr address = handle.AddrOfPinnedObject();

PopulateArray(address, count);

handle.Free();
```

---

It can also be done with unsafe code, which is somewhat more intuitive to read and remember:

```
int count = 5; 
float[] resultVertices = new float[count];
unsafe 
{
    fixed(float* ptr = resultVertices)
    {
        PopulateArray(ptr, count);
    }
}
```

---

Another alternative is to have C# allocate an unmanaged chunk of memory and pass that to the C++ method. This is better than what you're doing because you are not placing the responsibility of allocation/deallocation in the C++ library code and instead keeping that all in your C#. I know you want to avoid the coy but sometimes doing the copy is more performant than pinning objects, but it depends on how large they are. I recommend you do performance testing to determine which is best for your situation.

```
int count = 5; 
float[] resultVertices = new float[count];
IntPtr unmanagedMemory = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(count * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(float)));
PopulateArray(unmanagedMemory, count);
Marshal.Copy(unmanagedMemory, resultVertices, 0, count);
```

In all these scenarios you should set your C++ code to operate like this:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool PopulateArray(float* resultVerts, int vertLength)
{
    resultVerts[0] = 0.123f;
    // fill out the rest of them any way you like.
    return true;
}
```

If the array size is variable, then I recommend having a separate C++ method that calculates the size and returns it rather than having the C++ method allocate the memory.

Comment: I assume in your first code block you wanted to pass the address into PopulateArray() not ptr.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to allow C# to allocate the array (probably a safer alternative) then you could do this behavior with standard PInvoke attributes.

Change your C++ declaration to:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) bool PopulateArray(float resultVerts[], int resultVertLength)
```

and your C# declaration to:

```
[DllImport("Win32Library.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool PopulateArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] float[] resultVerts, int resultVertLength);
```

Your usage from the C# side would then change to:

```
var resultVertices = new float[5];
PopulateArray(resultVertices, resultVertices.Length);
```